# Why am I getting undefined from my onClick event on my anchor tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class GoalGrid extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleGoalClick = this.handleGoalClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleGoalClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(event.target.value);
        this.props.addPointValue(parseFloat(event.target.value));
    }

    render() {
        const goalButtons = Object.keys(this.props.goalsAndPoints).map(
            i => (
                <a
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                    key={i}
                    onClick={this.handleGoalClick}
                    value={this.props.goalsAndPoints[i]}>

                    {i} – {this.props.goalsAndPoints[i]}

                </a>
            ),
        );

        return (
            <div id="goals">
                <h4 id="goalsHeader">Goals</h4>
                <div id="goalGrid">
                    {goalButtons}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default GoalGrid;
```

I was originally mapping `goalButtons` to button elements and `handleGoalClick` was successfully gettings a numerical value. But when I update elements to anchor tags, it looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="1">Text</a>
```

Now I'm getting undefined. Why? I need these to be anchor tags rather than button tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I figured it out right after I posted to StackOverflow (all according to plan...). What I needed was:

```
event.target.getAttribute("value");
```